# How to add length and right angle to triangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following creates a triangle.

Q1. How can I add lengths such as 5cm, 6cm and xcm for each side.

Q2. How can I add a right angle sign to A?

```
 \item[b)]
      \begin{tikzpicture}
% Draw the triangle
        \draw[fill=gray!10]  (0, 0) coordinate (A) 
        -- (0,5) coordinate (C) 
        -- (6,0) coordinate (B) 
        -- (0, 0);

% Draw nodes
        \node at (A)[anchor=north] {A};
        \node at (B)[anchor=north] {B};
        \node at (C)[anchor=south] {C};
      \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

      \begin{tikzpicture}
% Draw the triangle
        \draw[fill=gray!10]  (0, 0) coordinate (A) 
        -- node[left] {$3$\,cm} (0,5) coordinate (C) 
        -- node[above right] {$5$\,cm} (6,0) coordinate (B) 
        -- node[below] {$4$\,cm}  (0, 0);
       \draw (0,10pt) -- ++(10pt,0) -- ++(0,-10pt);
% Draw nodes
        \node at (A)[anchor=north] {$A$};
        \node at (B)[anchor=north] {$B$};
        \node at (C)[anchor=south] {$C$};
      \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a `brace` decoration, you could add braces to the sides to indicate the lengths:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}

      \begin{tikzpicture}
% Draw the triangle
        \draw[fill=gray!10]  (0, 0) coordinate (A) 
        -- (0,5) coordinate (C) 
        -- (6,0) coordinate (B) 
        -- (0, 0);
       \draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt},decorate] 
         (A) -- node[below=4pt] {$4$\,cm} (B); 
       \draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt},decorate] 
         (B) -- node[above=4pt,sloped] {$5$\,cm} (C); 
       \draw[decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt},decorate] 
         (C) -- node[left=4pt] {$3$\,cm} (A); 

       \draw (0,10pt) -- ++(10pt,0) -- ++(0,-10pt);
% Draw nodes
        \node at (A)[anchor=north] {$A$};
        \node at (B)[anchor=north] {$B$};
        \node at (C)[anchor=south] {$C$};
      \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: \draw (0,10pt) -- ++(10pt,0) -- ++(0,-10pt);draws an angle, but these coordinates, - and + doesn't make any sense to me. How do you decide these?

Comment: @shin Those draw two sides of a square of side `10pt`. The drawing begins at the point `(0,10pt)` then go `10pt` to the right, and finally `10pt` downwards.

Comment: @shin These indicate relative coordinates as opposed to absolute coordinates.

Comment: @shin the `++` modifier adds the coordinates to the previous point and locate the origin in the given coordinate. From the PGF manual:
`You can add a single + sign in front of a coordinate or two of them as in +(1cm,0cm) or ++(0cm,2cm).
Such coordinates are interpreted differently: The first form means “1cm upwards from the previous specified
position” and the second means “2cm to the right of the previous specified position, making this the new
specified position.`